# I would like permanently redirect page within website

Tags: seo, 301-redirect

I have couple hundred dynamic pages within the website, that I think to eliminate.

They are indexed by search engine. I'm thinking to make permanent redirect to the home page of the website.

```
Example:

Dynamic page

http://www.domainname.com/dynamic_name.html


Home page


http://www.domainname.com/default.aspx
```

The home page has Google page rank 5. the dynamic pages has rank 0. If I do a redirect will it effect home page rank?

What will be the best way to eliminate dynamic pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the pages are being removed permenantly:

1. Serve a 404 error so users and search engines know the pages are gone forever
2. Show users a page that either contains similar or related content

   or

   Show users a message that the page they are seeking is gone and offer them an opportunity to go to main/important pages in your site, search your site, or view your sitemap if you have one. In other words, **do your best to help them find content they might be interested in and help them stay on your site**.
3. Do **not** just redirect them them back to your home page. That will confuse users (e.g. the people who might also be webmasters and may potentially link to your site).
4. If the dynamic pages have very low PageRank then doing the redirect won't give your home page a boost in its PageRank especially after the diluting factor is applied to any links associated to those dynamic pages.
5. It's hard to say definitively but doing a redirect to your home page *may not* be viewed upon as a positive thing by the search engines. At the very least, it is very possible they will see this as a bogus redirect and remove any positive effect such a redirect may offer.
6. PageRank is very overrated. It's value in Google's algorithm is so low that it really shouldn't even be a factor in any decisions you make.